# How do I sort a text file after the last instance of a character?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Goal: Sort the text file alphabetically based on the characters that appear AFTER the final slash. Note that there are random numbers right before the final slash.

Contents of the text file:

```
https://www.website.com/1939332/delta.html
https://www.website.com/2237243/alpha.html
https://www.website.com/1242174/zeta.html
https://www.website.com/1839352/charlie.html
```

Desired output:

```
https://www.website.com/2237243/alpha.html
https://www.website.com/1839352/charlie.html
https://www.website.com/1939332/delta.html
https://www.website.com/1242174/zeta.html
```

Code Attempt:

```
i = 0
for line in open("test.txt").readlines(): #reading text file
    List = line.rsplit('/', 1)            #splits by final slash and gives me 4 lists
    dct = {list[i]:list[i+1]}             #tried to use a dictionary 
    sorted_dict=sorted(dct.items())       #sort the dictionary

textfile = open("test.txt", "w")
for element in sorted_dict:
    textfile.write(element + "\n")
textfile.close()
```

Code does not work.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? What happens when you run the code? What do you want it to do instead? Have you tried debugging your code? Check out [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for some tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would pass a different `key` function to the [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) function.  For example:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    lines = sorted(lines, key=lambda line: line.split('/')[-1])

with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(lines)
```

See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) for a more detailed explanation of key functions.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried the code and it's combining the second and third lines. Any idea how I would fix this?

Comment: Better use `sort`, no reason to use `sorted` there.

Comment: @zackchess20 Add a newline to the end of `test.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

Before you run this, I am assuming [you have a newline at the end of your test.txt.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729692/why-should-text-files-end-with-a-newline) This will fix "combining the second and third lines".

If you really want to use a dictionary:

```
dct = {}
i=0
with open("test.txt") as textfile:
    for line in textfile.readlines(): 
        mylist = line.rsplit('/',1)
        dct[mylist[i]] = mylist[i+1]

sorted_dict=sorted(dct.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])

with open("test.txt", "w") as textfile:
    for element in sorted_dict:
        textfile.write(element[i] + '/' +element[i+1])
```

---

**What you did wrong**

In the first line, you name your variable `List`, and in the second you access it using `list`.

```
List = line.rsplit('/', 1)
dct = {list[i]:list[i+1]}
```

Variable names are case sensitive so you need use the same capitalisation each time. Furthermore, Python already has a built-in `list` class. It can be overridden, but I would not recommend naming your variables `list`, `dict`, etc.

*( `list[i]` will actually just generate a `types.GenericAlias` object, which is a type hint, something completely different from a list, and not what you want at all.)*

You also wrote

```
dct = {list[i]:list[i+1]}
```

which repeatedly creates a *new* dictionary in each loop iteration, overwriting whatever was stored in `dct` previously. You should instead create an empty dictionary before the loop, and assign values to its keys every time you want to update it, as I have done.

You're calling `sort` in each iteration in the loop; you should only call once it after the loop is done. After all, you only want to sort your dictionary once.

You also `open` the file twice, and although you close it at the end, I would suggest using a context manager and the `with` statement as I have done, so that file closing is automatically handled.

---

**My code**

```
sorted(dct.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])
```

means that the `sorted()` function uses the second element in the `item` tuple (the dictionary item) as the 'metric' by which to sort.

```
`textfile.write(element[i] + '/' +element[i+1])`
```

is necessary, since, when you did `rsplit('/',1)`, you removed the `/`s in your data; you need to add them back and reconstruct the string from the `element` tuple before you `write` it.

You don't need `+ \n` in `textfile.write` since `readlines()` preserves the `\n`. That's why you should end text files with a newline: so that you don't have to treat the last line differently.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def sortFiles(item):
    return item.split("/")[-1]

FILENAME = "test.txt"

contents = [line for line in open(FILENAME, "r").readlines() if line.strip()]

contents.sort(key=sortFiles)

with open(FILENAME, "w") as outfile:
    outfile.writelines(contents)
```